# Redundant Connection of Arrayed Component

Tags: modelica, dymola, fmi

Warning received claims I have a "redundant connection(s) (due to other connections)." I am linking one `HeatPort` to several components that expand through the use of an array. See the code segment below.

The use of `each` does not appear to work or I have no done it correctly.

```
Redundant connection(s) (due to other connections):
connect(topFrontExteriorConvection.solid, module3_PipeComponents[2].port_a);
connect(topFrontExteriorConvection.solid, module3_PipeComponents[3].port_a);
connect(topFrontExteriorConvection.solid, module3_PipeComponents[4].port_a);
connect(topFrontExteriorConvection.solid, module3_PipeComponents[5].port_a);
connect(topFrontExteriorConvection.solid, module3_PipeComponents[6].port_a);
in the connection set.
ecoCeramicRadiation.T =module3_PipeComponents[1].port_a.T =module3_PipeComponents[2].port_a.T =module3_PipeComponents[3].port_a.T =module3_PipeComponents[4].port_a.T =module3_PipeComponents[5].port_a.T =module3_PipeComponents[6].port_a.T =topFrontExteriorConvection.solid.T
Note that this is not an actual error, and the redundancy can be removed in several ways.
```

The balance of heat between the `.solid` and `.port_a` should be correct mathematically but I may not be setting up the balance correctly in Modelica. Please let me know if there is a way I can create these connections without them being redundant. Although this is only a warning, I receive a following ERROR based on these warnings.

`Edit 1` I have setup a secondary model where the component is no longer arrayed but instead copied several times in the model. The heat port is connected to several other heatports but I still receive the above message. The connections look like this: 
[image: Redundant Connection]

Is there something wrong with kind of connection?

`Edit 2` Adding code snippets. Below is the relevant code to the redundant connection warning. There is more code to this model but it was removed for brevity.

```
  parameter Integer numPipes=6 "Number of repeating pipes.";

  Buildings.HeatTransfer.Convection.Exterior topFrontExteriorConvection(
    hFixed=exteriorConvectionCoefficientFixed,
    conMod=extMode,
    azi=Azimuth,
    til=ecoCeramicTopPanelTilt,
    A=surfaceAreaTop);

  Components.Module3_PipeComponents module3_PipeComponents[numPipes](
    each segmentLength=segmentLength,
    each thicknessEco=thicknessEco,
    each pipeVolume=pipeVolume,
    each fluidFlow=fluidFlow,
    each initialFluidTemp=initialFluidTemp,
    each fluidDensity=fluidDensity,
    each pipeDiameter=pipeDiameter,
    each pipeLength=pipeLength,
    each surfaceAreaTop=segSurfaceArea);

equation
  connect(fluidInlet, module3_PipeComponents[1].flowPort_a);
  for i in 1:numPipes - 1 loop
    connect(module3_PipeComponents[i].flowPort_b, module3_PipeComponents[i+1].flowPort_a);
  end for;
  for i in 1:numPipes loop
    connect(ecoCeramicRadiation, module3_PipeComponents[i].port_a);
    connect(topFrontExteriorConvection.solid, module3_PipeComponents[i].port_a);
    connect(module3_PipeComponents[i].port_b, topInsulationConduction.port_a);
  end for;
  connect(module3_PipeComponents[numPipes].flowPort_b, fluidOutlet);
```

Comment: Could you provide the text of the model as it is usually difficult to see everything from the diagrams.
For arrays combined connections it is even more difficult as there might be for-loops with connect in them, and they are not shown at all in the diagram.

Comment: Hello @HansOlsson, thank you for the suggestion. I have added a code segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are the following lines:

```
for i in 1:numPipes loop
    connect(ecoCeramicRadiation,              module3_PipeComponents[i].port_a);
    connect(topFrontExteriorConvection.solid, module3_PipeComponents[i].port_a);
...
end for;
```

This implies numPipes*2 connections involving numPipes+2 connectors, which imply redundant connections if numPipes is large enough.

One way of avoiding that is:

```
for i in 1:numPipes loop
    connect(ecoCeramicRadiation,              module3_PipeComponents[i].port_a);
...
end for;
connect(ecoCeramicRadiation, topFrontExteriorConvection.solid);
```